# Examples where $\mathbb{E}{Y} > \mathbb{E}{X}$ but $\mathbb{E}{\log(Y)} < \mathbb{E}{\log(X)}$

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables, logarithms, expected-value

Are there examples where an inequality about expected values of two random variables reverses when the expected value of logarithm is considered? More specifically, are there random variables $X,Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}{Y} > \mathbb{E}{X}$ but $\mathbb{E}{\log(Y)} < \mathbb{E}{\log( X) }$?

Comment: Hint: you can find one where $X$ is constant and $Y$ takes only two values.

Comment: $3 + 0.1 > 1 + 1$ but $3 \times 0.1 < 1 \times 1$.

Comment: $E(\log X)$ is essentially the geometric mean of $X.$ So when $Y$ takes only values  between the AM and GM of $X,$ you've found an example. For example, if $X$ is a fair die, then the AM is $3.5,$ the GM is $\sqrt[6]{6!}\approx 2.99,$ so if $Y\in(3.0,3.5)$ you get an example.